# Problemas ao criar lista de listas

Tags: array, python-3.x, lista

Estou tentando fazer com que o programa crie uma lista com o nome dos arquivos encontrados no diretorio e dentro de cada indice desta lista, crie uma lista de strings com o conteudo que encontra dentro dos arquivos

tentei ir debugando os indices da forma que sabia e conclui que funciona na primeira vez que roda o loop e depois nao funciona mais

'''

```
infos = [[]]
for fileFound in os.listdir('.'):
    for i in range(len(os.listdir('.'))):
        infos[i].append(fileFound)
        textFile = open(fileFound)
        infos[i].append(textFile.readlines())
```

'''

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yan, é possivel fazer isso de duas formas sem abrir outro loop dentro do primeiro "for", exemplo:

1) Usando lista ([doc](https://www.devmedia.com.br/como-trabalhar-com-listas-em-python/37460)) o indice é numerico sequencial :

```
import os

infos = []

for fileFound in os.listdir('.'):
  if '.' in fileFound:
    nome_arquivo  = fileFound
    dados_arquivo = open(fileFound).read() 
    infos.append([nome_arquivo, dados_arquivo])
```

2) Usando dicionario ([doc](http://excript.com/python/funcoes-dicionarios.html)) o "indice" pode ser o nome do arquivo:

```
import os

infos = {}

for fileFound in os.listdir('.'):
  if '.' in fileFound:
    nome_arquivo  = fileFound
    dados_arquivo = open(fileFound).read() 
    infos[nome_arquivo] = dados_arquivo
```